# Se puede realizar esta consulta en Mysql donde se involucran 2 tablas que están relacionadas?

Tags: mysql

Tengo las siguientes tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tes, usuarios y registrados

Quiero hacer una consulta de la cual quiero obtener de la tabla test(idtest, nombre, fechaInicio y fechaFin). La consulta tiene dos condiciones, que la fechaFin sea mayor o igual a la fecha actual y la segunda condición es que un usuario con id 17 no este registrado con el test.

estas son las tablas con información

Tabla usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tes tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tablas registradas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta que espero teniendo en cuenta el usuario con el id 17 sería: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otras palabras, lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente: yo soy un usuario con id 17 el cual voy a realizar una prueba pero para poder presentar dicho test tengo dos condiciones, primero que la fechaFin del test sea menor o igual a la actual y la segunda la cual seria que mi id en este caso 17 no se encuentra registrado en alguna de estas pruebas.

Lo que intente hacer:

SELECT a.idtest, a.nombre, a.fechaFin from test a left join registrados b on a.idtest = b.test_idtest where DATE(a.fechaFin)>=CURDATE() and 17(este es el id del del usuario) != b.usuario_idusuario

Lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
¡Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @cami sie Consulta [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables). Quizas te sirva para lo que estas tratando de hacer. Se hace principalmente un doble inner join...

Comment: @Alexci voy a ver que encuentro, gracias

Answer (score 0):

no se si comprendí bien tu pregunta pero te comparto lo que entendí.

"Que un usuario se puede realizar el test, siempre que la fecha actual sea antes de la fechaFin del test y que el usuario no esté registrado ya en ese test".

Algo como esto:

```
Select b.idtest, b.nombre, b.fechaFin
    From usuarios a
    Inner Join test b On a.idUsuario = b.usuario_idUsuario
    Inner Join registrados c On a.idUsuario = c.usuario_idUsuario
    Where curdate() <= b.fechaFin
    And [aqui se sustituye por el usuario que quieras] not exists (Select idUsuario from registrados where test_idtest = b.idTest);
```

Si la consulta te devuelve los datos de id, nombre, fechaFin entonces el usuario puede registrarse porque la fecha es menor a la fechaFin y no está registrado en el test.

Si no devuelve datos la consulta entonces es porque no cumple con esas condiciones.

Me cuentas si te pude apoyar, saludos!!

Comment: me sale error en el NOT EXISTS, creo que estoy remplazando mal  lo hago asi And 1 not exists...                                                                                                                                      el 1 es el id del usuario

Comment: reemplaza el NOT EXIST por NOT IN, quizá funcione, te soy sincero lo he realizado con Oracle la sintaxis de MySql no la tengo a la mano ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer tantos joins como creas que esa necesario, por ejemplo

```
SELECT 
  a.idtest, 
  a.nombre, 
  a.fechaFin 
FROM test a
INNER JOIN usuarios u2 ON u2.idusuario = a.usuario_idusuario
LEFT JOIN registrados b ON a.idtest = b.test_idtest 
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.idusuario = b.usuario_idusuario
WHERE 
  DATE(a.fechaFin)>=CURDATE() 
  AND u.idusuario <> 1 -- tu usuarioid
  AND u2.usuario_idusuario = 1 --tu usuarioid
```

El primer join es la relacion de test con el usuario
el segundo join es la relacion de test con los registrados
el tercer join es la relacion de los registrados con los datos de los usuarios

Es una aproximación, el punto es que puedes utilizar los joins que necesites mientras la relacion sea la correcta.

EDIT: esta query retorna el usuario y test si tiene permiso, para el idtest proporcionado. en el caso de que quieras saber todos los tests que puede acceder el usuario solamente quitar el 'AND T.idtest'

```
SELECT 
    U.idusuario,
    U.nombre,
  T.idtest, 
  T.nombre, 
  T.fechaFin 
FROM usuarios as U,
LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        T.idtest, 
        T.nombre, 
        T.fechaFin,
        R.usuario_idusuario
    from test as T
    LEFT JOIN registrados as R on R.test_idtest = T.idtest AND R.usuario_idusuario = U.idusuario
    WHERE
        DATE(T.fechaFin) >= CURDATE()
        AND R.idregitrado is null
        AND T.idtest= 1 --id de tu test
) as T
    WHERE U.idusuario = 1 -- id de tu usuario
```

Comment: obtengo este error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'u2.usuario_idusuario' in 'where clause'

Comment: era u2.idusuario en el segundo AND , perdon.

Comment: no me arroja nada, pero ya no sale el error

Comment: AND u.idusuario is null OR u.idusuario <> 1 en el segundo AND, falto que u.usuario pueda ser null

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo pienso, esa consulta no esta bien, ya que solo funcionaria si el test le pertenece al usuario. mi enfoque esta mal.

Comment: ok, le agradecería si me puede ayudar, llevo varios días intentando solucionar esto y es lo único que me falta, el problema es el siguiente, yo como usuario voy a presentar un tes pero este tes solo lo puedo presentar si la fecha fin es mayor o igual a la actual y la segunda condición es que no este registrado ya en este test, gracias

Comment: Edite la respuesta agregando una query, chequela a ver si le sirve.

Comment: me da error en lateral is not valid at this position

Comment: falta coma al final de FROM usuarios as U  si no reconoce LATERAL después de eso, entonces su MySQL no lo soporta, LATERAL es soportado a partir de la version 8.0.14